# Linux USB installer does not see my internal SSD drive

Tags: linux, usb, system-installation

- Laptop Lenovo 710s.
- The hard drive is a Samsung internal SSD drive    250 gigabytes.
- Model: NVMe Samsung MZVLV256
- 45 gigabytes unallocated space.
- Intel ChipSet Sata Raid

Here is the issue I have tried EUFI install disks for Ubuntu, Debain, NixOs, and System Rescue. In ever case `fdisk -l reads`:

```
[root@nixos:~]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 977.5 MiB, 1024942080 bytes, 2001840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 7.5 GiB, 8054112256 bytes, 15730688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E5563D8F-B423-4FAB-BA48-4B650F70DD09

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 15730654 15728607  7.5G Microsoft basic data
```

`dmesg | grep sd`:

```
[root@nixos:~]# dmesg | grep sd
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000BD2F3000 005300 (v02 LENOVO SaSsdt   00003000 INTL 20141107)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000BD2C1000 000E73 (v02 LENOVO CpuSsdt  00003000 INTL 20141107)
[    0.442815] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq pm led clo only pio slum part deso sadm sds apst 
[    2.552254] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 15730688 512-byte logical blocks: (8.05 GB/7.50 GiB)
[    2.553754] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.554591] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[    2.555283] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[    2.556111] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    2.570653]  sda: sda1
[    2.572982] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    8.091883]  autofs4 squashfs sd_mod usb_storage hid_generic usbhid hid atkbd ahci libahci xhci_pci xhci_hcd libps2 libata usbcore scsi_mod crc32c_intel usb_common i8042 rtc_cmos serio dm_mod fuse nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 vfat fat loop
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 1903 (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d2f (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d31 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3a (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d14 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d48 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d21 (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d70 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9d23 (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 3166 (rev 99)
```

gparted gives the following error:

```
Could not stat device /dev/mapper/no block devices found - No such file or directory.
```

dmraid -ay
 No Block Devices Found

that is on nixos.

fast boot is turned off in windows 10.
Have googled quite a bit. 
Can't seem to access the internal hardrive from a usb boot disk so can`t install any linux. 
Let me know if you can help.

`[root@nixos:~]# lspci -nnk`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:1904] (rev 08)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0008]
lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:000f]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1903] (rev 08)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0008]
        Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:000e]
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0008]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:000e]
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:17.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:282a] (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:000a]
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d14] (rev f1)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d48] (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0005]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:000e]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:000d]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:000e]
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3166] (rev 99)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4210]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the current version of the ideapad 710s BIOS does not allow changing of the SATA/drive mode from RAID to AHCI. As a result, it is pretty much impossible to install Linux onto these systems. I've tried multiple combinations of things - completely wiped the drive, disabled UEFI, Secure Boot and enabled Legacy mode, etc - and nothing works.  The currently locked SATA mode basically prevents Linux from even seeing the SSD.  I've tried the latest versions of Ubuntu and Gentoo - both with the same result.

Source: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/ideapad-710s-and-Linux/td-p/3358780

Comment: Just to add changed to a Lenovo Yoga 500 and no issues also the tech specs for the 710s actually mention that the hard drive controller is raid only.